# How get a list of results of finished threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

Methods description:

Thread newThread (Runnable runnable)
Creates and registers a new Thread. Name of the thread should be "-worker-n", where n is a number of a thread. A ThreadUnion must monitor execution of a created thread - refer to results() method.

List results()
Returns a list of results of finished threads. No results must be returned for threads that are not finished yet. A result must contain a thread name, a timestamp when it finished execution and a Throwable if it was thrown

Note that your ThreadUnion implementation should be thread-safe and support concurrent thread generating.

```
public FinishedThreadResult(final String threadName) {
        this(threadName, null);
    }

    public FinishedThreadResult(final String threadName, final Throwable throwable) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.throwable = throwable;
        this.finished = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    public Throwable getThrowable() {
        return throwable;
    }
```

Test:

```
 void testResults() {
        ...
        final ThreadUnion threadUnion = ThreadUnion.newInstance(unionName);

        final Set<RuntimeException> exceptionsToThrow = ...;
        final int fineThreadsCount = 3;
        final int longThreadsCount = 2;
        final int shortThreadsCount = fineThreadsCount + exceptionsToThrow.size();
        final int allResultsCount = fineThreadsCount + longThreadsCount + exceptionsToThrow.size();

        final List<Thread> exceptionThreads = exceptionsToThrow.stream()
                .map(e -> threadUnion.newThread(() -> throwException(e)))
                .collect(toList());

        final List<Thread> fineThreads = Stream.generate(() -> threadUnion.newThread(this::printThreadName))
                .limit(fineThreadsCount)
                .collect(toList());

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final List<Thread> longThreads = Stream.generate(() -> threadUnion.newThread(() -> awaitLatch(latch)))
                .limit(longThreadsCount)
                .collect(toList());

        final LocalDateTime beforeStart = LocalDateTime.now();
        final LocalDateTime afterStart;
        final LocalDateTime afterShortThreadsFinish;
        final LocalDateTime afterLongThreadsFinish;

        final List<FinishedThreadResult> shortResults;

        try {
            startThreads(exceptionThreads, fineThreads, longThreads);
            afterStart = LocalDateTime.now();

            joinThreads(exceptionThreads, fineThreads);
            afterShortThreadsFinish = LocalDateTime.now();

            shortResults = threadUnion.results();
            assertEquals(shortThreadsCount, shortResults.size());
            assertEquals(expectedNames(unionName, 0, shortThreadsCount), resultThreadNames(shortResults));
            //!FAILs
            shortResults.stream()
                    .map(FinishedThreadResult::getFinished)
                    .forEach(finished -> assertAll(
                            () -> {
                                System.out.println("before "+beforeStart);
                                System.out.println("tread " + finished.toString());
                                assertFalse(finished.isBefore(beforeStart));
                            },
                            () -> {
                                System.out.println("after "+afterShortThreadsFinish);
                                assertFalse(finished.isAfter(afterShortThreadsFinish));
                            }
                    ));

            assertEquals(exceptionsToThrow, collectThrowables(shortResults));
```

I tried:

```
  private final String nameThread;
    private final Collection<Thread> syncResultsThreadList = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>());
    private final Collection<FinishedThreadResult> resultList = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>());
    private final AtomicInteger numberThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Map<Thread, FinishedThreadResult> resultMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
...
@Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {

        Thread thread = new Thread( r, nameThread + "-worker-" + numberThreads.get());
        numberThreads.incrementAndGet();

        syncResultsThreadList.add(thread);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, throwable) -> {
                resultList.add(new FinishedThreadResult(thread.getName(), throwable));
            });
        return thread;
     }

 @Override
    public  List<FinishedThreadResult> results() {
         List<FinishedThreadResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Thread tr : syncResultsThreadList) {
                resultMap.put(tr, new FinishedThreadResult(tr.getName()));
            }

        if (resultList.size() > 0) {
            for (FinishedThreadResult ftr : resultList) {
                resultMap.forEach((t, f) -> {
                   if (Objects.equals(f.getThreadName(), ftr.getThreadName())) {
                        resultMap.replace(t, f, ftr);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        resultMap.forEach((t, f) -> {
            if (!t.isAlive()) {
                results.add(f);
           }
        });

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(results);
    }
```

But sometimes timestamp is wrong. And sometimes throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Is the time stamp adjusted for your local time zone?

Comment: Yes, time stamp implements by LocalDateTime.now().

Comment: You didn't say which assertion actually fails, but the threads created by your `newThread` function only add anything to the `resultList` if the given `Runnable r` throws an exception. If the `fineThreads` Runnables don't throw any exception, then those will not add any results to the list. I would _expect_ the `assertEquals(shortThreadsCount, shortResults.size())` assertion to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a thread and than monitor when it finished execution and get its result read about [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface. It provides out of the box solution for your problem